# What happens if only a part of a question is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closing, questions, exact-duplicates

[Melee weapon usage by wizard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69703/melee-weapon-usage-by-wizard) has a couple of votes to close as a duplicate of [How do I set a mouse button to a regular attack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63413/how-do-i-set-a-mouse-button-to-a-regular-attack).  However the new question actually has three parts of it, only one part of which is a duplicate.  Closing the question as a duplicate when most of it isn't seems counter-intuitive.

How should these type of questions be handled?  Should the original question be edited to remove the duplicate question so only new questions remain?  Should it be closed?  Should it remain as is?

I guess in an ideal world the original asker should have asked each question individually, but alas this obviously isn't an ideal world.

Comment: Only partial duplicate is like only partial dead. Not really at all.

Comment: There's a big different between mostly dead and all dead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicate questions are edited out, and then the question is left open.

Comment: Possibly with a reference to the other question.  "I saw **this**, but ____" sort of thing.